# Transition is changing the size of the page when .dropdown hover{}

Tags: html, css, transition

the transition in `.dropdown:hover .dropbtn{...}` is changing the size of the page when the hover on `.nav li a:hover {...}` is not doing it which is good.
I tried to change the position in but it doesnt help. I am not sure what else I can do to solve this.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: 2.6px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

.dropbtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2.6px;
  }

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #333;
transition: 0.6s;
padding: 24px 10px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  transition: 0.6s;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 24px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Smart-Home</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> O firmie </a></li>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <li><a class="dropbtn" href ="indexKontakt.html"> Produkty </a></li>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> Nasi partnerzy </a></li>
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> Kontakt </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change <button> to an <a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that the actual change is.....

from: `<button  class="dropbtn" href ="indexKontakt.html"> Produkty </button>`

to:`<a class="dropbtn" href="indexKontakt.html"> Produkty </a>`

it should be pointed out that then the class 'dropbtn' should be removed and the styles be done through the `ul li` and `a` elements.

it should also be noted that nesting divs in ul li can be avoided and top level drop downs are not normally needed in a div container of their own.

i believe this is more helpful as its helps understand what is wrong or the issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation. It is more clear to me now.

Answer (score 2):

Below is updated snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: 2.6px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

.dropbtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2.6px;
  }

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #333;
transition: 0.6s;
padding: 24px 10px;
}

.nav li > a:hover {
  transition: 0.6s;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 24px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Smart-Home</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> O firmie </a></li>
        <li><div class="dropdown">
        <a  class="dropbtn" href ="indexKontakt.html"> Produkty </a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> Nasi partnerzy </a></li>
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> Kontakt </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```